# Ruby capital letter variables dilemma in algorithmic code

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions

Having recently started programming in Ruby, I noticed one small language feature that is really giving me a hard time — variables that start with a capital letter are automatically constants.

While I understand that this is by design, and does really help in most cases, it becomes a problem once one starts writing algorithms. By that I mean code that requires efficient and easy distinction between variables — say, `n` and `N`.

Here is a very simplistic example (I'm aware it's not a fully valid/rubyesque code, but I hope it illustrates my point):

```
def average(array)
  N = 0
  array.each { |n| N += n }
  N/array.length.to_f
end
```

Another example is subscripts — say, while doing a calculation in a physics problem, having `F_friction` and `F_weight` would be helpful but impossible in Ruby.

So, the question is: is there an accepted way of dealing with these variable names?

Comment: You could prefix the variable name with an underscore.

Comment: You could fork Ruby and drop constants altogether :)

Comment: You can disable all Ruby warnings (`ruby -W0`) and not be bothered anymore by constants reassignement, but this is evil: I am rushing for some holy water just for suggesting that.

Comment: @Eureka, you'll need a lot of it, you'll burn in hell for that one :)

Comment: Your sentence "variables ... are automatically constants" is self contradictory.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Afterlife uncertities solved, check :)

Comment: Why this nasty workaround for subscripts? wouldn't direct support for subscripts (via some font sensitive grammar) be nice?  ;-)

Comment: Btw, average can be more concisely written as `array.inject(:+) / array.length.to_f`.

Comment: @sawa What I meant to say was "variables, declared with a capital letter automatically become constants". I guess I should've elaborated there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually the solution is just to choose much more meaningful names. E.g.

```
def average(values)
  total = 0
  values.each { |value| total += value }
  total/values.length.to_f
end
```

Why is `F_weight` helpful. F is for Force?

Fine `force_weight`, erm no: `force_mass`. After all weight is a force.

Now if you were talking about N as in the set of natural numbers, I could see some point if N wasn't a local variable.

Comment: That is what I thought too, but the notion of meaningful names kinda breaks down, once you start having abbreviations longer that a few words. Say, we are writing code to calculate Bézier curve, `B_t`, which is in turn a sum of Bernstein polynomials, `B_rn`. Having capitals is almost essential there. I hope this kind of illustrates my question a bit better.

Comment: Why are you using abbreviations? I try not to, very hard. People keep asking me what they mean, worse still sometimes I have no clue...

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Readability should be the top priority. Just sometimes, I think, one really wants an almost direct translation from a mathematical notation into code; I guess I couldn't really convey that in my question.